# curl_setopt with CURL_POSTFIELDS parameter returning false

Tags: php, post, curl

I am having trouble setting the post parameters in my php code.  I have the following lines of code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "a=b");
```

On my local machine, the call to curl_setopt above works, and returns true. On my server, however, it returns false.  The only difference between the two that I can think of is that on my local machine I have php 5.3.8 and the server has 5.3.10.

Any ideas about why this is happening or what I can do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Additional info:
Those lines of code above are actually a result of me trying to debug the curl issue that  am seeing and narrow the problem down to the line that is failing. The problem I am encountering is actually in the the Twilio api. In my code I call:

```
$twilioClient = new Services_Twilio($twilioAccountSid, $twilioAccountToken);
$message = $twilioClient->account->sms_messages->create($fromNumber, $toNumber, $body);
```

and that call is throwing an exception.Tracing through the function call takes me to Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->call() function.  Line 62 (curl_setopt_array) is returning false event though it is working locally.  The code for that can be found here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php

Comment: could you please add your whole code from `curl_init()` to `curl_exec()`, or at least the essence of it?

Comment: Sure-- the code that is failing is actually a call in the Twilio api.   I'll add some more info to the question.

Comment: how can you be sure that it's `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` that makes `curl_setopt_array()` fail?

Comment: I edited the code to loop through the opt array and print out which call was returning false.

Comment: could it be that a check on proper url-encoding of the parameters is done? Allowed characters in the argument of `CURLOPT_SETFIELDS` should be `[-+_.&=a-zA-Z0-9%]` (square brackets excluded). Can you check that?

Comment: what is the size of your POST? Is it more than [post_maxsize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)? (shouldn't matter, since that is for incoming POSTs, but you never know...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing this code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
```

The definition of setting CURLOPT_POST to TRUE is: *TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind, most commonly used by HTML forms.*

You can read all about the various curl_setopt options here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: True--  I do set that in my code, but I cut it out here in the hopes of isolating exactly what works on my local machine vs what fails on the server. Maybe I should have added all of the code, its just that there are a bunch of options getting set (and suceeding) and I was hoping this would narrow down the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.